Hang in IIS Application Pool with RDS MySql Connection Open
We have a SAAS based platform with a single codebase running individual websites for clients. The client websites are automatically divided between multiple application pools. On average each application pool has 20 websites.
The software solution is .NET MVC5 hosted on AWS EC2 with RDS MySQL database. Things were working relatively fine until AWS forced us to upgrade to MySQL 8 version from the current 5.7.
As a consequence, we had to update our application to use MySql.Data 8.4 library. Since then, our websites periodically hang on MySqlConnection.Open call, and as a consequence end up hanging all websites on the application pool.
We tried several things, combinations of connection string, using async controllers to make sure we do not block the main thread, trying to catch as much data as we could to reduce database calls. While all this improved things, the issue continues with customer websites hanging all the time.
While we applied a temporary fix by automatically restarting the IIS service every few hours, this is no solution.
Can you help us resolve this issue?

Can you ensure that there is no way to run the older version of MySql until you pick apart the issue? I know RDS has many configurations to prevent an unwanted upgrade.

Hi,
Thank you for taking the time and for the reply.
No, AWS is charging a massive fee for customers that are still using MySQL 5 over an above the standard RDS charges. And, they will increase it in the 2nd year.  So, we have to continue with MySQL 8.

This is a very generic error, there is no specific cause for this, you can try to debug the cause using IIS Debug Diagnostics Tool, this tool will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.

Have you seen this thread pool extension designed to reduce overhead and improve performance when dealing with many concurrent connections -> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.4/en/faqs-thread-pool.html
